# React Country -> Province/State -> City selector?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I feel like this is pretty common that people want a selector that when you pick a country it narrows down province/states to that country then you pick state or province and it narrows down the city for you. Is there nothing on NPM for that? I saw country selector and country-province but nothing that goes from country to city. If nothing exists should I store all those in the DB or front-end? I'm assuming DB.

Comment: Did you find any package? How did you add this type of selector?

Answer (score 5):

You could use either of the two libraries.

1. https://github.com/country-regions/react-country-region-selector [React Component -> Provides Country and State]
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-state-city, [Standalone Library which provides Country -> State -> City]

If you want to store the data and search results on your own, i would suggest you to stored it in a DB, loading the data on frontend would be expensive on network.

Comment: country-state-city was super close except it's missing all cities for some states, making it lacking what I need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this React component [react-places-autocomplete](https://hibiken.github.io/react-places-autocomplete/) based on Google Places API.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using react country-state-city, but it consumes lot of space.